# how can I solve the error of installing pyaudio?

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, pyaudio

I am installing different python libraries for my voice assistant project. I installed "speechrecognization" but I am not able to add pyaudio.

I got an error stating that

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio", Collecting PyAudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
  Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
```

and

```
Could not build wheels for PyAudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried upgrading pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

also,

```
sudo apt install build-essential portaudio19-dev python3.10-dev
pip install pyaudio

brew install portaudio
brew link --overwrite portaudio
pip install pyaudio

python -m pip install PyAudio

pip install PyAudio --upgrade
```

OS: Mac M1 chip
Python 3.10.2

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing PyAudio using Homebrew and it worked
use the following command:

```
brew install portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

This will first install the portaudio library using Homebrew, and then use pip to install PyAudio, which is a Python wrapper for portaudio.

Comment: I don't understand, those are the same commands listed in the question...?

Answer (score 0):

From the PyAudio project page;
"*PyAudio provides Python bindings for* ***PortAudio*** v19, the cross-platform audio I/O library. With PyAudio, you can easily use Python to play and record audio on a variety of platforms, such as GNU/Linux, Microsoft Windows, and Apple macOS." https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/

The project page does in fact state that this python module creates *bindings* to the PortAudio api. The author lists the steps necessary to install on macOS as being 1) use homebrew to install PortAudio 2) use pip to install PyAudio module. I was able to verify personally that these steps work as of MacOS 13.0.1 on Intel based macbook pro.

*Installing Homebrew via terminal; `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)`

*Then installing PortAudio via brew; `brew install portaudio`

*and finally; `pip3 install pyaudio`